# Incremental insert into SQL column

Tags: sql-server

I have table with date column. I want to insert integer number: from first Monday to that Sunday 1, from second Monday to Sunday 2, etc...

How can I do this in SQL server?

Expected output:

```
03/14/16    1
03/15/16    1
03/16/16    1
03/17/16    1
03/18/16    1
03/19/16    1
03/20/16    1
03/21/16    2
03/22/16    2
03/23/16    2
03/24/16    2
03/25/16    2
03/26/16    2
03/27/16    2
03/28/16    3
03/29/16    3
03/30/16    3
03/31/16    3
04/01/16    3
04/02/16    3
04/03/16    3
04/04/16    4
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have date column but that second column i don't know how to get that values.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,[date column])
,DATEPART(WEEK,[date column]) ) FROM table
```

Comment: did u use the **PARTITION BY DATEPART(WEEK,[date column])** ?

Comment: Modified , plz chk now

Comment: Modified , plz chk now ( u can modify the order by clause as per your business logic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107626/discussion-between-abdul-rasheed-and-jack).

Comment: SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,[date column])
,DATEPART(WEEK,[date column]) ) FROM table

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the same as `DENSE_RANK`

You may also need to `SET DATEFIRST 1` if your locale doesn't have Monday as the first day of the week.

```
SELECT 
 MyDate,
 DATENAME(WEEKDAY, MyDate),
 (DATEPART(WEEK, MyDate) - DATEPART(WEEK,MIN(MyDate) OVER (ORDER BY MyDate)))
 + ((DATEPART(YEAR, MyDate) - DATEPART(YEAR,MIN(MyDate) OVER (ORDER BY MyDate))) *52) + 1 MyWeek
FROM MyData

MyDate                                    MyWeek
---------- ------------------------------ -----------
2015-12-26 Saturday                       1
2015-12-27 Sunday                         1
2015-12-28 Monday                         2
2015-12-29 Tuesday                        2
2015-12-30 Wednesday                      2
2015-12-31 Thursday                       2
2016-01-01 Friday                         2
2016-01-02 Saturday                       2
2016-01-03 Sunday                         2
2016-01-04 Monday                         3
2016-01-05 Tuesday                        3
```

**Edit** Fix year crossing

**Edit 2** Really fix year crossing, increment counter for each Monday (eg if first date is mid week), see example data.

Comment: it works, but after year change it will show negative values.

Comment: @jack fixed (I think :) )

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '2016-03-14'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  @start as [d],
        1 as [w]
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(day,1,[d]),
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEK,[d]) != DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(day,1,[d])) THEN w+1 ELSE w END
FROM cte
WHERE d < '2017-04-04')


SELECT [d], [w]
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: same problem when year changes, it shows different values

Comment: @Jack check now :)